# SSIS Package does not work after switching it to Don't save sensitive

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledbconnection

I have an SSIS package which runs a SQL command to truncate a table. The package works perfectly fine when it is on the ProtectionLevel "Encrypt sensitive data with user key", however I am trying to remove all encryption on it so I can run it as a job on the SQL server agent (following another solution: [SSIS issue Failed to decrypt protected XML node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297018/ssis-issue-failed-to-decrypt-protected-xml-node))

Somehow just changing this one setting causes the entire package to fail. The error says that the OLE DB connection that is used on the SQL Task cannot log in:

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "DestinationConnectionOLEDB". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

I check inside the connection "DestinationConnectionOLEDB" I am unsure why it provides this error as when I open the connection, and put in the credentials and test the connection, it gives me the "Test connection succeeded" Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ,which type of protection level you have set on your package?have you tried to ProtectionLevel=Don't save sensitive data ..

Comment: That is exactly what I am changing the protection level to when I say "I am trying to remove all encryption on it so I can run it as a job on the SQL server agent" this is the solution suggested in the link I put in the description. I am getting an error as a result of this.

Comment: This is a very old question and has many answers, althought they are all complicated. The simple answer is: always use windows authentication.